# Is there a way to define the preferred merge or diff tool under Unix?

Tags: environment-variables, diff, merge

I know that you can define the preferred editor by setting the `EDITOR` environment variable.

My question is if there is a similar solution for setting the preferred merge or diff tool.

Comment: For git, it uses the `merge.tool` configuration assignment.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there isn't any universal way; it depends on which version control system you are using, e.g.:

- Mercurial uses [a setting in `.hgrc`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration).
- git uses `merge.tool` configuration, as told in a comment.
- for svn, [you specify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4803881/1071869) in `/etc/subversion/config`.